# How to call an express.js handler from another handler

Tags: express, isomorphic-javascript

I'm building an isomorphic React application which is using express.js on the server. The client app makes a number of AJAX requests to other express handler which currently entails them making multiple HTTP requests to itself.

As an optimisation I'd like to intercept requests I know the server handles and call them directly (thus avoiding the cost of leaving the application bounds). I've got as far as accessing the apps router to know which routes it handlers however I'm struggling to find the best way to start a new request. So my question is:

How do I get express to handle an HTTP request that comes from a programatic source rather than the network?

Comment: Can you add some samples?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest create a common service and require it in both the handlers. What I do is break the business logic in the service and create controllers which handles the request and call specific services in this way u can use multiple services in same controller eg.

**router.js**

```
var clientController = require('../controllers/client-controller.js');
module.exports = function(router) {
  router.get('/clients', clientController.getAll);
};
```

**client-controller.js**

```
var clientService = require('../services/client-service.js');
function getAll(req, res) {
  clientService.getAll().then(function(data) {
    res.json(data);
  }, function(err) {
    res.json(err);
  });
}

module.exports.getAll = getAll;
```

**client-service.js**

```
function getAll() {
  // implementation
}

module.exports.getAll = getAll;
```

u can also use something like http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/ to make http calls from controllers and make use of them.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer my question. I'm building an isomorphic framework which will be consumed by others so cannot make modifications to their code.